# ColdFusion Production Server - Tuning for Performance

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to determine the optimal settings for my ColdFusion PRODUCTION server.  The server has the following specs.

> ColdFusion: Enterprise Version 10
>  O/S: Windows Server 2012R2
>   Standard 
>  Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v2 @ 2.20GHz
>   
>  Installed Memory (RAM): 20.0 GB 
>  System Type: 64-bit
>   Operating System, x64-based processor

My Java and JVM settings from the CFIDE are:

> Minimum Heap Size (in MB): 2048
>  Maximum Heap Size (in MB): 4096
>
> JVM Arguments
>   -server -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.home={application.home} -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home} -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/lib -Dorg.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER=true -Dcoldfusion.jsafe.defaultalgo=FIPS186Random

I have multiple websites running on this production server, all of which use ColdFusion.  The database server is completely separate, so all that this server is responsible for is the ColdFusion application and web server processes.

The websites are completely data-driven, all pulling from the database located on my production database server.  Lately, I've been seeing the ColdFusion service locking up, as it is maxing out the CPU.  The memory is stable, it's only the CPU that is maxing out.

Can anyone make suggestions as to how I can tune it to improve overall performance while reducing strain on the CPU?

Java Version

> java version "1.8.0_73"
>  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_73-b02)
>  Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)

Thank you!

Comment: What does "memory is stable" mean? How much space is left on the heap? How often and how long does the garbage collection run? Did you check for long running requests? I found [Fusion-Reactor](https://www.fusion-reactor.com) very helpful to monitor server performance.

Comment: There is no one-size-fits-all approach to server tuning. The only way is to perform load testing, make changes, load test, make changes, load test, etc. Until you find the settings that meet your preferred performance. Here is a good starting point - [Performance Tuning for ColdFusion Applications](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion_performance.html) And, by the way, **you are running an unsupported version of ColdFusion** and mainstream support for Windows 2012 ends later this year.

Comment: What version of Java are you on? Have you considered using G1GC insteal of ParallelGC?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running all of these sites on a single instance of ColdFusion? If so, I would recommend running multiple instances of CF. Each instance can run the same JVM settings given your total available memory.

```
Minimum Heap Size (in MB): 2048
Maximum Heap Size (in MB): 4096
```

So that's a max of about 16GB of memory allocated to a total of 4 instances of CF. Then you balance out the volume of sites run on each instance based on site usage. You might have one that needs its own instance and the rest can be spread across the other three.

It's also possible to run all of the sites on all of the instances using a load balancer to pass requests from one instance to another. Either approach should insure that one site doesn't cause the rest to run poorly or not at all.

Comment: Adrian J. Moreno - do you have any links/info you can provide on how to set up multiple instances?

Comment: Docs: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/using-multiple-server-instances.html